# Converting negative binomial regression model from SAS to R

Tags: r, sas, non-linear-regression

I have a dataset of subjects, who received TRT = "A" for a couple of weeks and then all of them switched to TRT= "B" for another couple of weeks. Event rates for each treatment was estimated using negative binomial regression in SAS as below:

```
PROC GENMOD;
               class ID TRT;
               MODEL EVENTS = TRT /link=log dist=negbin offset=lnTIME;
               repeated SUBJECT = ID;
RUN;
```

Now, I need to rerun the same analysis in R. I have tried glmer.nb function as follows:

```
glmer.nb (EVENTS ~ (1|ID) + TRT + offset(lnTIME) )
```

But I got slightly different results. Can anyone help?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Welcome to SO.